# UWP Hamburger navigation menu error when using visual triggers - XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm creating a Hamburger navigation UI for an UWP using Visual triggers and I get this error.
"An animation is trying to modify an object named 'HamburgerButtonMobile', but no such object can be found in the Page."
This is my code

```
 <VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="HamburgerButtonMobile.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</VisualState.Setters>
<Pivot x:Name="MoviesPivot" Title="MOVIES">
    <Pivot.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RelativePanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="72" Foreground="#FF21B255" FontWeight="Light" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" x:Name="titleName"/>
                    <Button x:Name="HamburgerButtonMobile" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="HamburgerButtonMobile_Click" RelativePanel.LeftOf="titleName" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" />
            </RelativePanel>
        </DataTemplate>
</Pivot.TitleTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your Visual Trigger can't see the item is because the item you're trying to access lives inside of a `DataTemplate`. It 'Doesn't Exist' yet

I *THINK* what you want to do is add the visual trigger to the `RelativePanel`.
Honestly it's hard to say without seeing more code.

```
<RelativePanel>               
   <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      <VisualStateGroup>
           <VisualState x:Name="BlahNameState">
             <VisualState.Setters>
                  <Setter Target="HamburgerButtonMobile.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
             </VisualState.Setters>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and I no longer get the error but it doesn't hide the button either. The visual triggers I have set for other elements outside the pivot work perfectly.

Comment: Okay well if you're not getting the error then your first problem is solved. I can't massage the code for you lol